# Laravel MorphPivot with two sides polymorphic relationships

Tags: laravel, pivot, polymorphism

Here is my current models' structure:

- Attribute models (CattegoryAttribute, LocationAttribute, etc.)
- Attribute pivot
- Attachable models (Event, Task, etc.)

There may be many attachable models (Event, Task, etc.)
Each attachable model may have many attributes, which may be of different types: CattegoryAttribute, LocationAttribute, etc.

Current schema looks like here:

[image: Current schema]

Event

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphTo;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class Event extends Model
{
    public function attributes()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Attribute::class, 'appendable');
    }
}
```

Attributes

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Attributes extends Model
{

    public function attribute()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function attachable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

Category

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    public function attribute()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(Attribute::class, 'attribute');
    }
}
```

This is working solution, it works like here:

```
$event->attributes->each(function ($attribute) {
    echo 'Attribute of class: ' . get_class($attribute->attribute);
    // Attribute of class: App\Models\Category, App\Models\Location, etc.
});
```

So I have intermediate table `attributes` on which elements I need to call separately `attribute` to get the final attribute object.

Is is possible to make it work like this:

```
$event->attributes->each(function ($attribute) {
    echo 'Attribute of class: ' . get_class(attribute);
    // Attribute of class: App\Models\Category, App\Models\Location, etc.
});
```

So the `attributes` table can act like a pivot table but with polymorphic objects on both sides of this pivot table?